# Has anyone installed Ubuntu on Atom/Celeron-based Slate PC?

Tags: installation, tablet

I'm going to buy one of following slate PC for Ubuntu system.
Has anyone installed Ubuntu 12.x LTS or later on following machine?
It is just for doing simple coding + qt application use.
3D support is welcome, however, it is not essential.

Gigabyte Wintelslate
HP ElitePad
Lenovo ThinkPad Tablet 2
ACER W5500/510

-Hyon

Answer (score 0):

I have 13.04 running on a Dell Mini 9 netbook.  This version actually operates better than the original 8.04 that was shipped on the netbook.  This netbook has Intel an Atom N270 1.6 GHz processor, 2MB ram and a 16GB SSD.